# How to compare an Oracle exception message with a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am new to C# and I'm struggling with very basic stuff... for instance I am now trying to compare an exception that I KNOW will print exactly the phrase "ORA-28007: the password cannot be reused" if I use `Response.Write(ex.Message)`. However, in the block below, the comparison between ex.Message and the string just provided fails and it returns that Unhandled Exception I've put in the else clause... How should I be comparing the exception with the string?

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   if (ex.Message == "ORA-28007: the password cannot be reused")
   {
     Response.Write(ex.Message);
     // TODO : Correct the exception to be presented in the popup instead of the same page.
     // display = "The password cannot be reused! Pick a new one.";
     // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
     //     "Error.", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
   }
   else
   {
     Response.Write("Unhandled exception: " + ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: your error message may be slightly different. try `ex.Message.Contains("ORA-28007")`

Comment: normally Exceptions has an `HResult` property with a numeric value that you can [check](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.hresult(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Why dont you put a break point on the If() statement and check the result of ex.Message in the debugger ?

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleExceptionClass.htm) you can catch `OracleException`s instead of `Exception`s and get some more details by looking at the `Errors` property, which gives a list of [OracleError](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleErrorClass.htm#ODPNT1577) objects:

```
catch(OracleException oex)
{
    foreach (OracleError error in oex.Errors) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error Message: " + error.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("Error Source: " + error.Source);

        if(error.Number == 28007) 
        {
            // do specific stuff
        }       
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers and help! I used the tip from L.B (ex.Message.Contains("ORA-28007"))...